# Android : How to detect onTouch event on a view, with touch down outside the view?

Tags: android, swipe, touch-event

In an Android fragment, I have a GridLayout with views in it.

I would like to be able to detect when a user swipes over a view, even if he initially touches down outside of it. I've included a diagram to illustrate what I mean here :

[image]

Is there a simple way to do this (without using coordinates to see if the touch point is in the view)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You solve this using `View.OnTouchListeners`.

- Set `OnTouchListeners` both root view as well as your view.
- Check for Events and actions ACTION_DOWN(touch event start),ACTION_UP(touch event over)
- Set flags as per need for inside touch or outside touch.

basically you need capture events as well as points too.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Do you have an example, since I'm not sure to understand what you mean in your last step?